# How to validate required in nested map

Tags: elixir

I'm working with Elixir.

I receive some attributes and I'm using them to create a `location`. Attributes is something like:

`attrs = %{latitude: 123.2, longitude: 123.4, metadata: %{timestamp: "2015-05-05T01:31:54", accuracy: 1}}`

To create I use:

```
location
|> cast(attrs, [:latitude, :longitude, :metadata])
|> validate_required([:latitude, :longitude])
```

Is there a way I can validate required for metadata.timestamp?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using part of what Harun answer and another answer from a different forum I solved with that:

```
defp validate_metadata_contains_timestamp(changeset, field) do
  validate_change(changeset, field, fn (current_field, value) ->
    case Map.fetch(value, "timestamp") do
      {:ok, _} -> []
      :error -> [{current_field, "The field metadata must have a timestamp"}]
    end
  end)
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create another schema for your metadata, and embed one `Metadata`. That would enable you to cast & validate the fields in your metadata. This is how the code would look like:

```
defmodule Location do
  use Ecto.Schema

  schema "location" do
    field :latitude, :float
    field :longitude, :float
    embeds_one :metadata, Metadata
  end

  def changeset(location, attrs) do
     location
     |> cast(attrs, [:latitude, :longitude, :metadata])
     |> validate_required([:latitude, :longitude])
     |> cast_embed(:metadata)
  end
end
```

and your Metadata:

```
defmodule Metadata do
  use Ecto.Schema

  embedded_schema do
    field :timestamp, :utc_datetime
    field :accuracy, :integer
  end

  def changeset(metadata, attrs) do
    location
    |> cast(attrs, [:timestamp, :accuracy])
    |> validate_required([:timestamp])
  end
end
```

This would be the way to go structure to validate nested maps using Ecto Schemas, but ofc. you could write your own validation function, [here](https://medium.com/@QuantLayer/writing-custom-validations-for-ecto-changesets-4971881c7684) is an example on how to do that.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. This field metadata had a structure defined, specifying its fields. But now I'm changing it to just a map field with no specification so it can receive different kind of information.
I think the way to solve this will be custom validation, that you also suggested.